# For loop with zip

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, for-loop

I am looking for some help, I have this example

```
numbers=['Sub1','Sub2','Sub3']
Value=[60,45,30]
Y = pd.Series()
for number,i in zip(numbers,Value):
    Y[number]=math.cos(i)
    print(Y)
```

I get this result

```
Sub1   -0.952413
dtype: float64
Sub1   -0.952413
Sub2    0.525322
dtype: float64
Sub1   -0.952413
Sub2    0.525322
Sub3    0.154251
dtype: float64
```

but what I hope to get is

```
Sub1   -0.952413
Sub2    0.525322
Sub3    0.154251
```

or

```
-0.952413
 0.525322
 0.154251
```

because I will need those values to complete the code.
Thanks
BR
Beginner

Comment: just unindent the `print` outside the loop and see what you get

Comment: Thanks!  it worked :)

Comment: That works, though there is an undesired "dtype: float64" at the end. You can also just print(number, Y[number]) in your very same code and you will get what you are looking for!

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
list(zip(numbers,[f'"{math.cos(i):.6f}' for i in Value]))                                                                                                                           
[('Sub1', '"-0.952413'), ('Sub2', '"0.525322'), ('Sub3', '"0.154251')]
```

or:

```
pd.DataFrame(list(zip(numbers,[f'{math.cos(i):.6f}' for i in Value])))


      0          1
0  Sub1  -0.952413
1  Sub2   0.525322
2  Sub3   0.154251
```